Ubuntu run docker with --net=host ，but can not access the services inside the container
forexample, run a jupyterlab container with -p 8888:8888, we can access the services inside the container from outside(host pc);
however run it only with --net=host, can not access the services inside the container.
system is  ubuntu22.04
docker version is 26.0.0
with the --net=host, we can ping the gateway or other local network pc  in the container.
In fact, I encountered this issue when using the isaac sim container. Just to simplify the problem, I used jupyterlab for testing and explanation
docker run --name isaac-sim --entrypoint bash -it --runtime=nvidia --gpus all -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" --rm --network=host 
-e "PRIVACY_CONSENT=Y" 
-v ~/docker/isaac-sim/cache/kit:/isaac-sim/kit/cache:rw 
-v ~/docker/isaac-sim/cache/ov:/root/.cache/ov:rw 
-v ~/docker/isaac-sim/cache/pip:/root/.cache/pip:rw 
-v ~/docker/isaac-sim/cache/glcache:/root/.cache/nvidia/GLCache:rw 
-v ~/docker/isaac-sim/cache/computecache:/root/.nv/ComputeCache:rw 
-v ~/docker/isaac-sim/logs:/root/.nvidia-omniverse/logs:rw 
-v ~/docker/isaac-sim/data:/root/.local/share/ov/data:rw 
-v ~/docker/isaac-sim/documents:/root/Documents:rw 
nvcr.io/nvidia/isaac-sim:4.0.0
TCP: 47995 to 48012
TCP: 49000 to 49007
TCP: 49100
UDP: 47995 to 48012
UDP: 49000 to 49007

Host networking generally disables Docker's entire networking stack; it isn't usually a best practice and it's rarely necessary.  If your setup works with a docker run -p option to publish a single Jupyterlab port, can you just keep using that?

thank you for your advices. however, i use "--net=host" is for the nvidia issac-sim container which contain many ports to explose. it is not so convinence to map each port to the host manuly. is anyone can help? thanks
